# Pharo: #subclass:instanceVariables... message personalized

Tags: metaprogramming, pharo

I am fighting against the Object message #subclass:instanceVariableNames:classVariableNames:poolDictionaries:category, in order to manipulate subclasses of an specific class.
I have RareClass with a class method #subclass:coposes...etc and want to do:

```
RareClass
 subclass: #RareSubclass
 composes: #SomeMagic
 instanceVariableNames: ''
 classVariableNames: ''
```

in the browser.
whether this method should return a class, (and i think it does) it is not working at all, im getting parsing errors when i try to 'save'...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using OmniBrowser with the Refactoring Engine loaded?

The Refactoring Engine enforces the standard class templates to enable undo on any action performed in the browser. Obviously that cannot work with custom class definitions.

As a workaround you can do one of the following:

- Use the traditional browser that has no undo functionality (evaluate `Browser open`),
- Get rid of the refactoring functionality in OmniBrowser by unloading the package "OB-Reactory", or
- Update the code in `RBAddClassChange` to support your use case.